# split_config.arm64_v8a.apk Crash on Android release - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

I am getting this crash on Android released app. I didn't use to get this error in dev builds. And also, it seems like its affecting a small number of users. I am also not using crashlytics.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000085094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__memcpy+292)
  #01  pc 0x000000000061c278  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #02  pc 0x00000000001d20a8  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #03  pc 0x00000000001d369c  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #04  pc 0x00000000001e1c00  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #05  pc 0x0000000000601fb0  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #06  pc 0x00000000001da6a4  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #07  pc 0x00000000001dde94  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #08  pc 0x000000000185105c  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #09  pc 0x000000000184f37c  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #10  pc 0x000000000184d6dc  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #11  pc 0x000000000191c240  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #12  pc 0x0000000000952c9c  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #13  pc 0x0000000000952bc0  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #14  pc 0x00000000002af964  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #15  pc 0x00000000002bd828  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #16  pc 0x00000000001deaa8  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #17  pc 0x000000000056984c  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #18  pc 0x00000000005699c4  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #19  pc 0x0000000000206b70  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #20  pc 0x0000000000207d30  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #21  pc 0x0000000000207d70  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #22  pc 0x0000000000207fb4  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #23  pc 0x00000000003399fc  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #24  pc 0x0000000000351a6c  /data/app/~~rl7ZWwW2NDGA5rRb9K9nEA==/{PACKAGE_IDENTIFIER}-OBaHBkLOrFpnjTcok9CC8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #25  pc 0x000000000043dd54  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148)
  #26  pc 0x000000000020a2b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+4016)
  #27  pc 0x0000000002041094  /memfd:jit-cache
```

The play store shows the error title as

```
[split_config.arm64_v8a.apk]
SIGSEGV
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very useful if you build appbundle, in case you want to deal with google play

you need to see this: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

you delete you cache with `flutter clean` and rebuild `flutter pub get`

for realease you can use `flutter build appbundle`

Comment: Yes, I am always using the `flutter build appbundle` . I used this when I got this error as well.

Comment: please plug your phone and try flutter run --release

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it on my phone, its on a very specific Android devices